# Where can I find the Firebase Realtime Database JAVA library for a wrap to B4X

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

For all my Android projects I use a popular RAD Tool called "[B4X](https://www.b4x.com/)" 
It converts easy readable sourcecode to JAVA and compiles it to Android or IOS etc.

In order to make use of existing Libraries (e.g. GitHub, ...) the JAVA files will be wrapped to B4X-libs so that the functionality can can be used with the RAD Tool.

So the question is "Where can I find the JAVA files of the Firebase Realtime Database" library?

Answer (score 0):

The plain Java SDK for Firebase is considered a "server side" SDK. Go to the [setup page for server SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup) and follow the instructions for Java. The current latest [version 3.0.1 can be found here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-server-sdk/3.0.1/), but I recommend starting from the linked documentation.